# function uses multiple asynchronous interfaces Promise MapSeries

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, promise, cucumberjs

```
return Promise.mapSeries(_.times(lineCount(reader)), i => {
        let dbFilter = { RefNumber : i }
        return expectData.dbDataExpected(dbCollection, dbFilter)
            .then(() => {
                console.log("Data: ", expectData.dataDB)
            })
    })
```

The above code is from cucumber step definition!
WHen I run the test I receive the following error:

**Error: function uses multiple asynchronous interfaces: callback and promise
to use the callback interface: do not return a promise
to use the promise interface: remove the last argument to the function**

Do you have any idea why i got this error?

Comment: You are trying to return a promise (.then()) from a promise, try returning a value in your .then

Comment: I updated the description with the function dbDataExpected which get data from mongo! how should I proceed in this case?

Comment: You should probably initialize a variable outside of your .then, set the data from the .then to the variable on the outside, then return that variable instead of returning the .then(), when you return the .then() you are returning a promise, but by setting the variable on the outside, you are returning your data.

Answer (score 21):

When implement a step definitions in case if you have more parameters than those defined in the scenario, then you will receive this Error.

Eq.

Scenario:
When the user creates "car1" and "car2"

Step definition:

```
When('the user creates {string} and {string}',function(p1:string, p2:string, p3:string){
...
})
```

Comment: exactly. Cucumber step def related error message could be quite misleading